# Class ColumnChartBuilder example not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem that my app-script does not show the chart I create.
To test it I took the example from docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/column-chart-builder?hl=lt)
and tried to run it. I gave the permissions it asked for when executing this script

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var sampleData = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Year")
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales")
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses")
      .addRow(["2004", 1000, 400])
      .addRow(["2005", 1170, 460])
      .addRow(["2006", 660, 1120])
      .addRow(["2007", 1030, 540])
      .addRow(["2008", 800, 600])
      .addRow(["2009", 943, 678])
      .addRow(["2010", 1020, 550])
      .addRow(["2011", 910, 700])
      .addRow(["2012", 1230, 840])
      .build();

  var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
      .setTitle('Sales & Expenses')
      .setXAxisTitle('Year')
      .setYAxisTitle('Amount (USD)')
      .setDimensions(600, 500)
      .setDataTable(sampleData)
      .build();

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

No error messages and no chart is shown.

Comment: See [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts?hl=lt)

Comment: If you want to add a chart to your spreadsheet, you should be using [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart) instead, and [provide the range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#addRange(Range)) you want to get the data from. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I need to get the data from variables, I calculate values from the sheet, but they are ' spread all over' , and I would like to use same script for several sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Charts Service works by rendering an image of the chart on the server. If you want to insert a chart created that way into a spreadsheet, you'll need to use [the `Sheet.insertImage()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row).

Here's a working example:

```
function insertChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var sampleData = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Year")
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales")
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses")
      .addRow(["2004", 1000, 400])
      .addRow(["2005", 1170, 460])
      .addRow(["2006", 660, 1120])
      .addRow(["2007", 1030, 540])
      .addRow(["2008", 800, 600])
      .addRow(["2009", 943, 678])
      .addRow(["2010", 1020, 550])
      .addRow(["2011", 910, 700])
      .addRow(["2012", 1230, 840])
      .build();

  var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
      .setTitle('Sales & Expenses')
      .setXAxisTitle('Year')
      .setYAxisTitle('Amount (USD)')
      .setDimensions(600, 500)
      .setDataTable(sampleData)
      .build();

  // Insert the sheet image into cell A1.
  sheet.insertImage(chart.getBlob(), 1, 1);
}
```

---

Given your comment above, it looks like you explicitly do not want to use an [`EmbeddedChart`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart).

One drawback of this approach is that when the underlying data is updated, you'll need to re-execute your Apps Script function to generate an updated chart.

An `EmbeddedChart` allows the chart to dynamically update as the underlying data is changed within the sheet. It's also a bit simpler in terms of the implementation:

```
function insertEmbeddedChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Assuming a sheet with only a grid of cells that matches 
  // the data manually specified above.
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();

  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart().asColumnChart();
  var chart = chartBuilder.addRange(dataRange)
      .setTitle('Sales and Expenses')
      .setXAxisTitle('Year')
      .setYAxisTitle('Amount (USD)')
      .setNumHeaders(1)
      .setPosition(1, (sheet.getLastColumn()+1), 0, 0)
      .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```